# How to add leading zeros to the fields of a Fields Date control

Tags: orbeon

I want to prevent Orbeon from removing leading zeros in fields for day and month. If I type in e.g. "04" I would like to keep that value instead of changing it to "4".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is with the regular *Date* field if using Form Builder, or an `xf:input` bound to a node of type `xs:date` if writing XForms by hand, then set the following property, and the leading 0 of days and months in date input fields will be kept when the date is entered by users, or added if not present in what users entered:

```
<property as="xs:string" 
          name="oxf.xforms.format.input.date" 
          value="[M01]/[D01]/[Y]"/>
```

Comment: The property is already set to have value [D01]-[M01]-[Y], but it doesn't work. I'm using `fr:fields-date` control, should it behave in the same way?

Comment: `fr:fields-date` switches the order of day/month depending on `oxf.xforms.format.input.date` since Orbeon Forms 4.6.3 (issue [#1803](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1803)). Maybe you are using an older version of Orbeon Forms?

Comment: Oh, I see, with `fr:fields-date` I notice the behavior is that leading zeroes are removed (unless you switch from, say, "6" to "06", then temporarily the leading zero remains. This is not configurable at the moment.

Comment: Bottom line is that changing this would require making changes to [`fields-date.xbl`](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources-packaged/xbl/orbeon/fields-date/fields-date.xbl).

Comment: Thanks, do you have any suggestions how should I modify 'fields-date.xbl' to make this work?

Comment: Search for `month-from-date` in the code. When the date as stored in the XML changes (because the user changed the value, or some other reason), the values in the fields get reset based on that value. And the `month-from-date()` just returns the month "number", without leading zeros. I imagine that if you always want leading zeros, you could add them there. And of course, you would want to do the same for the day in addition to the month.